# Combining Machine learning models depending on predicted value

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I am building the ML prediction for quite standard task: number of features = 30, the result value, that I have to predict is a real number between 0 and 1. After analysing data, I've discovered that the data looks quite different for ranges [0, 0.2), [0.2, 0.4) ... [0.8, 1). I've come up with the idea to build 5 models, one for each range and combine them to get better prediction. In order to detect which model to use, I will build another model (probably with NN, SVC or whatever) to predict the range for the value (5 ranges above) and then will apply one of five models accordingly.

Two questions arises here:
1. Does it makes sense? Could it improve the prediction quality?
2. I don't think this idea is unique and I am the first one. Could somebody point me to same/similar approaches?

Comment: Yes, I think this approach can give you some better results. One possible approach will be to use kmeans clustering and after that any good model like NN, tree based model etc.

Answer (score -1):

I too faced the same problem when i was working with that kind of data .i normalized all the feature between 0 to 1 and u go with any model u will get good classification.

Comment: thanks, but this is not about this. I would like to build different models for different ranges, because it looks like they differs significantly